# android in-app testing error

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I am developing android In-App with 10 In-App product.I complete integrate Android Billing library, the Google test account and setting the Product id, but when I am click on Accept & Buy button the following error occurs

```
your order could not be processed please try again.
```

What is the reason for this error. What I am doing wrong?

```
public void onClick(View v){ 
    if(BillingController.isPurchased(context, MainActivity.ITEM_ID[position])) { 
        String msg=(String) holder.txtViewname.getText(); 
        Intent intent= new Intent(context,RecipeMenu.class); 
        intent.putExtra("name", msg); 
        intent.putExtra("id", position); 
        context.startActivity(intent); } 
    else{ 
        BillingController.requestPurchase(context, MainActivity.ITEM_ID[position], true /* confirm */); 
    } 
} 
});
```

Comment: can you post the error and block of code where it is getting error?

Comment: public void onClick(View v) 
   {
    
    if(BillingController.isPurchased(context, MainActivity.ITEM_ID[position]))
          {
     String msg=(String) holder.txtViewname.getText();
     Intent intent= new Intent(context,RecipeMenu.class);
     intent.putExtra("name", msg);
     intent.putExtra("id", position);
     context.startActivity(intent);      
      
    }
    else{
     BillingController.requestPurchase(context, MainActivity.ITEM_ID[position], true /* confirm */);
    }
    
      
   }
        });

Comment: if any body have complete android in-app demo then please send me.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android provide us one example for this same In-app billing example. Please refer [Android In-app](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html). And name of that is market_billing. You can find it at android-sdk/extras/google/market_billing.

Comment: if any other demo then please send me.